# Semi-Blind-fighting with firearms in nWoD

Tags: combat, chronicles-of-darkness-1e

What happens when you see someone, draw your weapon, and suddenly a smoke grenade explodes, or the room goes dark? What penalty needs to be applied to a Dex + Firearms roll? Is it the same as blind fighting? What if you have no idea where your opponent or your friends are in subsequent turns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

-1 to attack enemy whose position you can accurately approximate.
-3 in subsequent turns.

Describe combat scene in terms of abstract shapes and silhouettes. ALL combatants are fair game. The GM should keep a mental picture in their head of where everybody is. Confuse PCs through vague descriptions.

To figure out where allied/friendly PCs are, have them make [Presence + Wits/Expression] vs [Wits + Composure]. Exceptional success on either side equals exact position now known -- before then it's all relative.

Comment: Why presence in combination with wits or expression? (the presence part surprised me there instead of for example composure)

Comment: Yeah... I can see Presence + Expression (successfully communicating that you're in that location) but I'm not sure what Wits is doing there.

Comment: Sticking to the plan under duress; having the wits to realize you need to communicate your position; these could be why. Though personally, I'd say Presence/Wits + Expression, maybe penalty to using Presence. It's much, MUCH more a matter of simply maintaining a calm enough mind to communicate at all than it is a matter of how you convey your personality.